# Lumen Model::find() does not select on primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I want to select an item from the table `board` by it's PK which is `boardId`.
However the `Board::find(2)` or `Board::find(1)` returns all items, regardless of given parameter.

I have the following table:

[image: table]

With corresponding Lumen Model:

```
class Board extends CustomModel
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'userId', 'boardName', 'private'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'boardId';

    protected $table = 'board';
}
```

Custom Model is:

```
abstract class CustomModel extends Model
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';

}
```

Calling it with:

```
$boardId = 2;
return Board::find($boardId)->get();
```

Also tried:

```
$boardId = 2;
return Board::find($boardId)->first();
```

And the following:

```
$boardId = 2;
return Board::find($boardId)->toSql();
```

Returns: `select * from 'board'`. So there is no `where boardId = ?` or something, which is the problem. What am I doing wrong ?

I'm running PHP 7.2.0 and Lumen 5.5.2. Queries on other models work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've said you're calling it with `get()`:

```
return Board::find($boardId)->get();
```

But you shouldn't add `get()` because it will return a collection of all objects. Just do this:

```
return Board::find($boardId);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, but can I specify additional 'where' parameters? Like `->where('userId', $userId);`

Comment: @Jeroen it doesn't make sense to use `where()` with `find()` because it returns one object by its primary key. If you want to use `where()`, use `get()` to get collection or `first()` to get first object found. For example `Board::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();`

Comment: Actually `return Board::where('userId', $userId)->find($boardId);` is what I wanted, but I had `find` first and then `where`, which doesn't work. Thanks!

(And why it makes sense in my case: the user requests an item and must also own that item, which is the `userId` field)

Answer (score 0):

Just erase the ->get() method this will works for you

I hope be useful